# Bamboo.io integration with XLSform hosted on ona.io like formhub was providing, or REST service

Tags: android, json, bamboo, survey

In Formhub, in the form management page, there was a button on the right to connect to bamboo.io . Doing that gave me a handy URL having all the collected data in a JSON, through which I could dynamically load latest collected survey data in my application. See screenshot.
[image]

As an example, all entries [submitted on this form](https://fddmk.enketo.formhub.org/webform) (and its ODK Collect counterpart), were collecting **[at this URL in JSON format](http://bamboo.io/datasets/f3facf491ae649d3a6c4162c16a89304)** which I could then import into my javascript and do mapping, data visualization, etc.

I'm using formhub's successor, **ona.io** now because formhub.org isn't loading half the time, and I read in some article that they don't intend to keep it up and one should go to ona.io now to do the same thing. It's the same thing (at much better speed, I can see that formhub.org was having server problems), But it's *missing the easy bamboo.io integration*. There is a "REST Services" tab mentioned below in the form's dashboard..

[image]

..that I can't make sense out of. What am I supposed to enter as "service URL" ?

I tried looking up ona.io's documentation but it's all for API and involved CURL commands etc. I'm checking out bamboo.io and even there I'm not getting any help. Everywhere they're going into advanced usage of custom servers, API's CURL GET etc. But I just want the simple live JSON data through a simple link [that I was getting in formhub](http://bamboo.io/datasets/f3facf491ae649d3a6c4162c16a89304).

I'm open to any other methods if available.. the end goal is to have a URL that carries all the accumulated data submitted by the form in JSON or CSV format. I want to import JSON (or CSV) from this set URL in my javascript on a web page hosted on my own server.

Note that it's not possible for me to self-host an ODK Aggregate instance. Ona.io is doing that for me.

In the traditional way of exporting data at ona.io (and formhub before it), the system creates a new file each time you export, with a timestamped file name. It doesn't auto-generate any single URL having latest data.. one has to go there and generate manually. That won't do... need a fixed URL which will have all latest data JSON or CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way. `ona.io` provides the same thing natively; I don't need `bamboo.io` (besides, even that is being retired same as formhub!)

All you need to do to get started, is to go here:

`https://ona.io/api/v1/data?owner=[your usename]`

From there you'll find URL's to the data collected by your forms, and you'll get the direct URLs for getting the data in JSON / CSV / many other formats.